# New Wamp Server installed but I can not see some WordPress pages

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I start a newly installed wamp server, the wamp-icon is green, I select Localhost and the browser goes to `http://localhost/`, which is ok.
Then I select my WordPress site `wp-20150719`, but the browser goes to `http://wp-20150719/` and browser display:

> Firefox can't find the server at wp-20150719.

So I manually change the URL in the browser to `http://localhost/wp-20150719/` and can go to my site. I login and go to "Pages" and edit my frontpage, 
then I "Preview changes" and the page is correctly displayed.

So I edit another page "Contact", the URL is `http://localhost/wp-20150719/contact/`, and hit "Preview changes", go to `http://localhost/wp-20150719/contact/`, and then I get this error:

> Not Found. The requested URL /wp-20150719/contact/ was not found on
>   this server. Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port
>   80

The permalink is `http://localhost/wp-20150719/?p=8`

I go to my site `http://localhost/wp-20150719/` and the frontpage is displayed, but when i use the menu to go to the other pages I get a "Not Found" error.

I have changed the permalinks several times, flushed the cache and restarted the browser and server, after a few days the problem is still the same.

I am on a Windows 8.1, the server is on `C:\wamp`, The WordPress theme is default Twenty Fifteen. Skype is not a problem.

It looks like they have changed the software, but the download page is without that information, you have to go to the forum. Now you must hack the software in several places to create virtual hosts, or hack it so that it works like before. 
So hundred thousind people are running around the internet to figure out if there is something wrong with their computer, or what, please correct me if I am wrong.

Edit 24-07-2015

I followed the tutorial below about creating a virtual host, it looked ok, but still same result.
questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server
Not Found. The requested URL /wp-20150719/eksempel-side/ was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
The URL: /localhost/wp-20150719/eksempel-side/

So I started the cmd.exe in administreror mode and wrote: net stop dnscache, and then net start dnscache, and restarted the computer.
Then I installed a new WordPress site, wp-20150724

New wordpress install:
1) create a new virtual host, like stated in the tutorial: project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server
2) When installing WordPress, do this; Database Host (leave this empty)
The WordPress site is up and running, but I get a 404 again. The localhost in the URL is gone (I think this is suppose to happen).

http://wp-20150724/eksempel-side/
Not Found. The requested URL /eksempel-side/ was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at wp-20150724 Port 80

The frontpage is there like before: http://wp-20150724/

Edit 26-07-2015

I made a new virtual host and installed a new WordPress, and in the WordPress install process I set the Host to my new site; wp-20150726

In the WordPress Dashboard if I set the pritty permalink to Default, the site works ok: `http://wp-20150726/?page_id=2`

But if I set the pritty permalinks to /%postname%/ I get an 404
Not Found. The requested URL /eksempel-side/ was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at wp-20150726 Port 80

Comment: Could you check the `RewriteBase` value in your htaccess? And about the links, you can use the `code block`.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-20150719/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp-20150719/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)

Comment: Deleted Wamp Server, installed the C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 x64. Installed EasyPHP, now WordPress works.